# rails app extremely slow

Tags: localhost, ruby-1.9.3, performance

I know there are lots of similar questions but I wasn't able to find a solution from any of those questions. So here we go..
I am using Ubuntu 12.04 on a sony vaio. I am running Rails 3.2.8 with Ruby1.9.3-p194. I am using thin server instead of webbrick. I have mongoid, elasticseaerch and redis running as well.

the page load is taking extremely long (over 10+ mins) on localhost. I know the app is not slow because it works on my colleagues' macbooks just fine. I am not sure what is causing it to have a very high loading time.

any tips is appreciated. i am really sad/unhappy as it is slowing me down considerably at work. i asked my colleagues but none of them seem to know the answer.

the app runs fine on company's production machine. it's only on my laptop that seems to be the problem. keep in mind that I have a very fast laptop (i5, 6gb RAM)

Answer (score 0):

Look at your logs. Use `tail -f` on the console to watch various logs. In your rails app, look at `tail -f log/development.log` You'll also want to look at your thin server logs. Since your coworkers are running the same codebase, it's probably not any of the actual code in rails taking that long. So your first step is to determine at which point in the http request is your app getting stuck for 10 minutes.

Also, make sure you have the same db as your colleagues. Eliminate as many variables as possible and start with your knowns.

Questions I'd ask myself:

- Is the request reaching rails immediately?
- Is another component (redis, mongodb) causing the problem due to your local config?

That said, a 10 minutes request that actually completes is bizarre - are you overriding timeouts?

Comment: thank you for your reply. i think it's reaching the rails server immediately but response seems to be very long. i am not sure if redis or mongo causing any trouble. any tips on how i can check that? and how do i override timeouts?

Answer (score 0):

How much memory and CPU is Rails using? How much memory and CPU is free? Rails apps van sometimes leak memory and crawl to a stop.

Comment: thanks for the reply. rails is using around 191 - 300mb of memory depending on the type of work it's doing. it uses around 2% to 5% cpu (again, depending on the task). on avg, there is 50% free memory (although swap memory usage seems to be very high) and lots of cpu left (around 70-80% free)

Comment: so i had a 256MiB of swap space which was maxing out. now i changed it  to 2.2GB (added 2GB more) but still no improvement. i added rails-dev-tweaks and i think it reduced the time a little bit but still unusable due to high loading time.